Signatures in Solana tx
Is it possible to send Solana transaction signed with the account, that is not in the account list?
At least Anchor forbids me to insert signature not correspondent to any account list, is it Solana rule or just an Anchor property?

All accounts that are read or written to during a transaction need to be part of the transaction. If an account is supposed to pay fees it needs to be writable because its deducting the lamport fees from that account so it defintelly needs to be in the transactions accounts.
